# Unity - Client and server control same Player Object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am coding a simple game where the two players control a character and need to avoid objects falling from the top of the screen. Both the players control the same character, so one player clicking "Left" should cause the character on the other player's screen to also move left.

My current attempt at this is having my default Player prefab in NetworkManager be a blank, and having my actual Player object be part of the Background. The issue I am having is that when I try to send the position from the client to the server, I do not have authority. My movement class is attached to the Player and is below.

```cs
public class PlayerMovement : NetworkBehaviour {

   public Button movementL, movementR;    
   public float speed;    
   private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;

   [SyncVar(hook = "OnChangeForce")]
   public Vector2 currentForce = new Vector2(0, 0);

    void Start () {
      rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

      Button tempL = movementL.GetComponent<Button>();
      tempL.onClick.AddListener(OnClickL);

      Button tempR = movementR.GetComponent<Button>();
      tempR.onClick.AddListener(OnClickR);
   }

   void OnChangeForce(Vector2 current)
   {
      rigidbody2D.AddForce(current);
   }

   void OnClickL()
   {
      if (isServer)
      {
         currentForce = new Vector2(0, 0);
         Vector2 move = new Vector2(-1, 0);
         currentForce += move * speed;
      } 
      else
      {
         GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().AssignClientAuthority(GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().connectionToClient);
         Debug.Log(hasAuthority);
         CmdOnClickL();
      }
   }

   void OnClickR()
   {
      if (isServer)
      {
         currentForce = new Vector2(0, 0);
         Vector2 move = new Vector2(1, 0);
         currentForce += move * speed;
      }
      else
      {
         CmdOnClickR();
      }
   }

   [Command]
   void CmdOnClickL()
   {
      OnClickL();
   }

   [Command]
   void CmdOnClickR()
   {
      OnClickR();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Unity Networking you have either a Master Client (who is Client + Server at the same time) and another Client, or you have a dedicated server + 2 or more clients. The one with the server role is the one who owns the scene and thus is the owner of all GameObjects within this scene unless they are specifically assigned to another player.

This is already done for the object which you set as player prefab, but as you said you are trying to move another object within this scene. As this is in your case not done by the server, but by the client, on an object which actually belongs to the server you get the Authority Exception. Keep in mind that every client can only manipulate variables on objects that actually belong to it.

The best way would be to use the PlayerPrefab for the Player object as it should be (so it contains the actual player object which is manipulated over the network), but you can also try to set the Authority with [NetworkIdentity.AssignClientAuthority](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkIdentity.AssignClientAuthority.html). That way you can give the authority over the object to the player it should belong to.

Another approach could be to have all GameObjects owned by the server and only sending player input to it, so the server moves all your GameObjects, but with that you would give up a lot of comfort of unity syncing your GameObjects for you. Nethertheless depending on your project it might be worth it, as you have way more control over everything.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! The issue I ran into with AssignClientAuthority was how to call it. Since PlayerMovement is within Player, I would need to assign the server Player's authority to the client Player's authority? Is that correct, and if so, how on earth do I make a function call like that?

Comment: sry overlooked that. In your code it seems that you are assign the object the NetworkIdentity that it already has, you should be able to get the right one from a NetworkIdentity on the GameObject thats created from your PlayerPrefab. You should be able to check which identity belongs to which client by using NetworkIdentity.connectionToClient.address. (note that this only works on the server)